# Project Euler #8 Wrong answer, explanation needed

Tags: python

Disclaimer :- I don't need the solution. I just want to know why my code is not producing correct answer.

I made the following code for the Project Euler question 8 which basically asks to find 13 adjacent numbers in a 1000 block of numbers which has the greatest product.
Here is the code :-

```py
que = 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934 \
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843 \
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511 \
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557 \ 
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113 \ 
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749 \ 
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866 \ 
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776 \ 
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243 \
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397 \
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482 \
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474 \
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881 \
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586 \
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042 \
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408 \
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188 \
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606 \ 
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725 \
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450 \

end = 0
nxt = 12
total = 1
temp = 0
while nxt < 1000: 
    for i in que[end:nxt]:
        total *= int(i)
        if total > temp:
            temp = total

    end += 1
    nxt += 1

print temp
```

Answer, I am getting - 283606606020024000
Can anyone explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    nxt = 13
```

and

```
    while nxt < 1000: 
        for i in que[end:nxt]:
                    total *= int(i)
        if total > temp:
            temp = total
        total = 1
        end += 1
        nxt += 1
```

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you. Sorry, if I sound ignorant as I am new to programming, but doesn't list indices start at 0, so changing nxt to 13 would mean 14 numbers?

Comment: >>> len("73167176531330624919225119674426"[0:12])
12
>>> len("73167176531330624919225119674426"[0:13])
13

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should reset `total` after each loop:

```
end = 0
nxt = 13
total = 1
temp = 0
while nxt < 1000: 
    for i in que[end:nxt]:
        total *= int(i)
        if total > temp:
            temp = total

    end += 1
    nxt += 1
    total = 1
```

Comment: I believe you are correct. But it is still giving wrong answer(`4702924800`), Any idea why?

Comment: As elisha robinson says, `nxt` should be set to 13

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you. Sorry, if I sound ignorant as I am new to programming,  but doesn't list indices start at 0, so changing nxt to 13 would mean 14 numbers?

Comment: In Python the first index is always included while the last one is always excluded. This means for exapmle slicing with `[2:4]` will give you the entries 2 and 3, but not 4. So if you want a slice of size 13 you need to use `[0:13]`

Comment: Don't worry, I'm always happy to help and anwer questions :)